# Can you put mods on GTA 5 on ps4?

Tags: ps4, grand-theft-auto-v, mods

Can you put mods on GTA 5 on PS4? I want to use [this mod](https://www.gta5-mods.com/player/vic-vance-all-outfits-from-vcs).

I don’t use gta online.

Comment: Except if you want to jailbreak your PS4, and thus break the PS TSO, and then break the GTAV TSO by installing mods, no. And both of them I would not recommend. Jailbreaking your PS4 has good chances to brick it, and then having a mod on GTA5 has good chances that the moment you connect to an online session, you are banned. And all that for some bonus outfits? Its really not worth it.

Comment: I don’t use gta online ?. .

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, yes. Kind of.

> Well, technically, you can actually get GTA V mods on PS4, but not officially. Rockstar Games hasn’t endorsed the use of mods, nor is it an intentional feature of the console version of the game. If you do want to install GTA V mods on your PS4, you’ll need to make use of an exploit within the PS4’s firmware, as well as go about not updating your system or the game. As a result, it’s far from a practical thing to do if you find yourself playing a lot of different games on your system.

Source, [Twinfinite](https://twinfinite.net/2018/01/install-gta-v-mods-ps4-how-to/).